# set select box value from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a data table, and each row has a set of columns having a date input boxes(Jquery datepicker) and one of the column in table has a dropdwon box values as Yes and No. when any of the date input box is selected with a value, then i should prepopulate the dropdown with Yes (by  default it is No). using onselect event i pass the date box id, with that id i make out the dropdown id. The ID generated for date box is "tableId:row number in table:dateID", so in my case it is generated as "vendorTbl:0:rskDate".

```
$( ".rejct_input_date" ).datepicker({                                            
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  onSelect: function(selected,evnt) {
  updateRiskIdentified(evnt);
  }});
```

Now in updateRiskIdentifed function i use the date id and i frame the DDL id as like

```
function updateRiskIdentified(value){                    
        var dateIdval = value.id;
            dateIdval = dateIdval.substring(0, dateIdval.lastIndexOf('_')) + "_rskIdntfd";
            var riskId = "#"+dateIdval+" ";
            alert(riskId);
            $($riskId + "option[value='1']").prop('selected', true);            
    }
```

Now i could generate the id i need, the last is giving unsupported psuedo ":0". Then i replaced dateIdval = dateIdval.replace(/:/g,"\\:"); to escape the ":". But the error message is "unsupported psuedo "\:0".
Here is my options

```
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="Y"></f:selectItem>
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
```

and generated HTML:

```
<select name="vendorArtifacts:0:_rskIdntfd" class="af_selectOneChoice_content" id="vendorArtifacts:0:_rskIdntfd" style="width: 100%;"><option value="0">Yes</option><option value="1" selected="">No</option><option value="2">N/A</option></select>
```

Comment: Are those `option`s or other things (`selectItem`)?

Comment: Show how you're calling `updateRiskIdentified`. What's in `value`?

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: @Barmar i have updated question with the value i am passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We haven't this jquery selector: `$($value "option[value='Y']").prop('selected', true);` .

At least after the $value you need a **+** to be a jquery selector. Below is a sample:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<select id="gate">
        <option value="x">x</option>
        <option value="Y">y</option>
    </select>

<script>
  var $value = '#gate ';
        $($value + "option[value='Y']").prop('selected', true);
  </script>
```

Do not forget the space after the '#gate '.

Answer (score 1):

The `.replace()` call should work.

You also don't need to use the `option[value="1"]` selector. Just set the value of the `<select>` element.

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  updateRiskIdentified(this);
});

function updateRiskIdentified(value) {
  var dateIdval = value.id;
  dateIdval = dateIdval.substring(0, dateIdval.lastIndexOf('_')) + "_rskIdntfd";
  dateIdval = dateIdval.replace(/\:/g, "\\:");
  var riskId = "#" + dateIdval;
  console.log(riskId);
  $(riskId).val("1");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="foo:bar:0_rskIdntfd">
  <option value="">Default</option>
  <option value="1">Choose 1</option>
  <option value="2">Choose 2</option>
</select>

<button class="button" id="foo:bar:0_button">Click</button>
```

Comment: This is the generated HTML `<select name="vendorArtifacts:0:_rskIdntfd" class="af_selectOneChoice_content" id="vendorArtifacts:0:_rskIdntfd" style="width: 100%;" onchange="alert(this.id);"><option value="0">Yes</option><option value="1" selected="">No</option></select>` and here is the updated function` updateRiskIdentified(value){
     
 $("#vendorArtifacts\\:0\\:_rskIdntfd").val('1').prop('selected', true);  
 }`

Comment: Why have you hard-coded the ID in the function, instead of using the `value` argument?

Comment: I have added more details to my question. Now it has details on why i hardcode or generate the id.

Comment: I'm not sure why your `.replace()` code didn't work. I've added a code snippet to my answer that demonstrates that it should.

Comment: it worked now, little modification in getting the element $(document.getElementById(dateIdval)).val("1");

Comment: If you use `document.getElementById` you don't need to replace the `:`. You also don't need to use `$(...)`, just use `document.getElementById(dateIdval).value = "1";`